# Favicon not working in Firefox if the page is in Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning, app, app-builder, favicon

We have requirement for adding Favicon for Lightning Home page which was built in Lightning App Builder. If the page is in Tab or Preview mode I am able to see favicon, but the samepage is in Lightning App Builder I am able to see salesforce default favicon.

Comment: have you tried other Fireforx version(s) - maybe this is a browser issue?

Comment: I have tried in new version of Firefox. Yes maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting browser specific issues, make sure you include the following:

> -browser name
>
> -browser version
>
> -device being used

Validate that you are using the latest browser version and see if you can reproduce the issue, test with other device(s) as well.

If the issue persists, contact browser support, for ex.

for google chrome:

> https://support.google.com/chrome

Firefox:

> https://support.mozilla.org/

Or last but not least, Salesforce support. unfortunately, there isint much we can do here for these specific issues.